# HTML Autoplay one video then loop another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to re-create the header video that robinhood.com has. Where it temporarily plays one video then loops another one. Here's what I tried to get it working:

```
  <video autoplay="1" class="header-video" id="first_video" preload="1">
      <source src="Video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
  <video class="header-video hidden" id="video_loop" loop="1" preload="1">
      <source src="Video2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
```

I thought this would work but it plays the first video then freezes, not playing the second video which is supposed to loop. All help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where do you start playing the second video? (You have to manually call `play`, it won't start automatically)

Comment: If I put autoplay on the second video tag it still won't play after the first video finishes. What I'm looking for is how to automatically play the second video right after the first one is playing

Comment: ok, first off, you only need `autoplay`, not `autoplay="1"`.

Comment: @Jonco98 it works fine the way they have it. Autoplay is a boolean value, if anything is set for autoplay it will be treated as "true."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just inspect their code and solve it the same way they are? Take a look at the `setupVideos()` function here: https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/CACHE/js/23d3f56c2529.js

HTML:

```
<video autoplay="1" class="header-video" id="first_video" preload="1">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoFirst.mp4">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoFirst.webmhd.webm">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoFirst.ogv">
</video>
<video class="header-video hidden" id="video_loop" loop="1" preload="1">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoLoop.mp4">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoLoop.webmhd.webm">
  <source src="https://brokerage-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/marketing/video/RobinhoodHomepageVideoLoop.ogv">
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#first_video').bind('ended', function() {
    $('#first_video').remove();
    $('#video_loop')[0].play();
    $('#video_loop').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks, I did review their code and tested it but didn't work. I thought it might have something to do with javascript but wasn't 100% sure. Greatly appreciated APAD!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
  <title>websunumu</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
   body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: red;
   }
   #output {
    width: 200px;
    height: 320px;
   }
   #buffer {
    display: none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#close").click(function(){
            $(".sunum").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
 <h1>transparan video</h1>
   <div class="sunum">
   <video id="video" loop="1" preload="1" autoplay style="display:none">
    <source src="compressed.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"' />
       </video>
   <canvas width="200" height="640" id="buffer"></canvas>
   <canvas width="200" height="320" id="output"></canvas>
  <p>
            <a href="#" id="pause"><img src="pause.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/></a> 
            <a href="#" id="start"><img src="play.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="#" id="close"><img src="close.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/></a></p>
            </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  (function(){
   var outputCanvas = document.getElementById('output'),
    output = outputCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    bufferCanvas = document.getElementById('buffer'),
    buffer = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    video = document.getElementById('video'),
    width = outputCanvas.width,
    height = outputCanvas.height,
    interval;
   function processFrame() {
    buffer.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    // this can be done without alphaData, except in Firefox which doesn't like it when image is bigger than the canvas
    var image = buffer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
     imageData = image.data,
     alphaData = buffer.getImageData(0, height, width, height).data;
    for (var i = 3, len = imageData.length; i < len; i = i+4) {
     imageData[i] = alphaData[i-1];
    }
    output.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
   }
   video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(processFrame, 40)
   }, false);
   // Firefox doesn't support looping video, so we emulate it this way
   video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    video.play();
   }, false);
   document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    video.play();
    event.preventDefault();
   }, false);
   document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    video.remove();
    event.preventDefault();
   }, false);
   document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    video.pause();
    clearInterval(interval);
    event.preventDefault();
   }, false);
  })();
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code gives an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Given your other deleted answer to this question, it's not clear to me if this is an attempt to answer this question, with the other answer providing a link to a functional example, or if you are trying to ask a new question (your other answer appeared to be clearly a new question). If you are attempting to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), then please click that link to do so. If you were trying to add an example for this answer, then you should [edit] this answer to provide it here.